# Fetching model instance from a multiple direct relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models

Can anyone help me fetch data from this model structure? because i have a hard time doin this for hours now.

**First I would like to get all distinct `SubSpecialization` from all `Doctor` which has a given `Specialization.title`**

**Secondly I would like to get all `Doctor` which has a specific `Specialization.title` and has no `SubSpecialization`.**

Here is the `Doctor` model

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    room_no = models.IntegerField()
    floor_no = models.IntegerField()
    contact_no = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True, null=True)
```

This is the model `Doctor` relationship is connected to `Specialization`and `SubSpecialization`.

```
class DoctorSpecialization(models.Model):
    doc = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, models.DO_NOTHING)
    spec = models.ForeignKey('Specialization', models.DO_NOTHING)

class DoctorSubSpecialization(models.Model):
    doc = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, models.DO_NOTHING)
    sub_spec = models.ForeignKey('SubSpecialization', models.DO_NOTHING)
```

This is where i would make a criteria.

```
class Specialization(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=45)
    point = models.IntegerField()

class SubSpecialization(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

There is no direct relationship between the `Specialization` and `SubSpecialization` please help.

Comment: As far as I understand, you're trying to have a many-to-many relationship between `Doctor` on one side and each of `Specialization` and `SubSpecialization` on the other. What's the need for the models `DoctorSpecialization` and `DoctorSubpecialization` then?

Comment: I mean you could use a `ManyToManyField` between `Doctor` and `Specialization`/`Subspecialization` directly.

Comment: @MuhammadSaeedArabi oh yes that is what the structure is thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your specialization and subspecialization are both many-to-many relationships with Doctor. You should declare that explicitly, and drop those intervening models unless you need to store other information on them.

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    ...
    specializations = models.ManyToManyField('Specialization')
    subspecializations = models.ManyToManyField('SubSpecialization')
```

Now you can query for all the subspecializations for doctors who have a specific specialization:

```
SubSpecialization.objects.filter(doctor__specialization__title='My Specialization')
```

Your second query doesn't make sense given the fact there is no relationship between specialization and subspecialization, you'll need to clarify what you mean by "no subspecialization in a specific specialization".

**Edit**

To find doctors who have a specific Specialization and then no subspecializations at all:

```
Doctor.objects.filter(specialization__name="My Specialization",
                      subspecialization=None)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response sir, i would like to clarify the second query which  is supposed to get all `Doctor` which has a given `Specialization.title` AND do not have a records (`id`) in `SubSpecialization`. Hope i explain it plainly. And please wait as i'm working for your answer.

Comment: Are you sure this is the right structure in the first place? It sounds like you want a doctor to have a single Specialization, and then a number of SubSpecializations which relate to that single Specialization.

Comment: I think not because a doctor may had a multiple specialization and subspecialization sir.

Comment: OK fair enough, but I still don't understand your second query then. You want to find doctors who have a specific Specialization and then *no subspecializations at all*?